# Using defaultdict to replace try and/or if statements in python

Tags: python, try-catch, defaultdict

I have recently found and started using default dictionaries to replace several more bulky constructs. I have read in 'the zen of python' that one of the key points of python is "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."

Based on that criteria (or perhaps more practically based on memory usage, or speed) which of the following (or something totally different) would be best? I have a hunch that the first is correct, but would like other people's opinions.

```
my_dict = defaultdict(int)
for generic in iterable:
    my_dict[generic] +=1
```

or:

```
my_dict = {}
for generic in iterable:
    if generic not in my_dict:
        my_dict[generic] = 1
    else:
        my_dict[generic]+=1
```

or:

```
my_dict = {}
for generic in iterable:
    try:
        my_dict[generic] += 1
    except(KeyError):
        my_dict[generic] = 1
```

Same can be said of using my_dict = defaultdict(list) and using append functions. Assume that multiple for loops, or other conditionals are used rather than simply counting generic values from a single iterable as that would obviously have different features.

Comment: For what you're doing here, use [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: `defaultdict` is the best of the three but, as @PauloAlmeida said, it's better to use `Counter` if you're just using ints.  Use `defaultdict` when you actually want to call methods of the default type `d=defaultdict(list); d[0].extend([1,2,3])` etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Paulo Almeida commented, for the example you posted the "obvious" solution is to use a `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
my_dict = Counter(iterable)
```

And that's it.

As for the other snippets you posted, and assuming the `my_dict[key] += 1` was just for the example and your general question is about "how to best populate a dict": `collections.defaultdict` is the right choice for homogeneous dicts (same type of values for all keys) where the type has a default value (numeric zero, empty string, empty list...). The most common use case I can think of is for populating a dict of lists (or sets or other containers).

Now when neither `collections.Counter` nor `collections.defaultdict` solve your problem, you have three possible patterns:

- look before
- try/except KeyError
- `dict.setdefault(key, value)`

The try/except solution will be faster if you expect the key to already exist - a try/except block is very quick to setup but costly when the exception is raised. As far as I'm concerned I don't recommand it unless you are *very very very* sure about what your data looks like now *and* what they will look like in the future.

The "look before" solution has an almost constant cost, and while not free it's still quite cheap. That's really your safest bet.

the `dict.setdefault()` solution has about the same cost as the "look before" one, BUT you also have the constant cost of instanciating a default object, that will often be thrashed immediatly. It was a common pattern some years ago but since the `collection.defaultdict` appeared it's of rather marginal use, not to say mostly useless.

Comment: For future readers, in Python 2.7, `try/except` will outperform `LBYL` and `dict.get` if you expect less than about 25% of the keys in aggregate to fail. (If, on average, each entry will be hit at least four times, it's faster.) EAFP is faster and only gets faster as that rate increases (@ 1% miss rate, by almost 40%). That being said, `defaultdict` out performs EAFP in all cases by a decent margin (10-20%). See the [repl.it](https://repl.it/Fm5X/3)

Answer (score 3):

If you insist on using a dictionary or defaultdict, the first one is the best. For counting, however, there's a lovely class called Counter in collections:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter()
>>> for generic in iterable:
...     c.update(generic)
```

Or even shorter:

```
>>> c = Counter(iterable)
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a script to test the performance of these 3 ways according to a situation in which I needed to choose the most performant way. Of course, the results will vary depending on the data you need to work with.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import random
import time

# build data
data = []
for x in range(0, 1000):
    data.append(
        { "name": "performance test", "company_id": random.randint(1, 9999), "platform": { "name": "stack", "last_name": "overflow" } }
    )

def perf_defaultdict():
    t0 = time.time()
    d = defaultdict(lambda:[])
    for x in data:
        d[x['company_id']].append(x['platform'])
    t1 = time.time()
    total = t1-t0
    print('defaultdict', total)
    return d

def perf_ifelse():
    t0 = time.time()
    d = {}
    for x in data:
        if x['company_id'] in d:
            d[x['company_id']].append(x['platform'])
        else:
            d[x['company_id']] = [x['platform']]
    t1 = time.time()
    total = t1-t0
    print('if else', total)
    return d

def perf_tryexcept():
    t0 = time.time()
    d = {}
    for x in data:
        try:
            d[x['company_id']].append(x['platform'])
        except KeyError:
            d[x['company_id']] = [x['platform']]
    t1 = time.time()
    total = t1-t0
    print('try/except', total)
    return d

# run
d1 = perf_defaultdict()
d2 = perf_ifelse()
d3 = perf_tryexcept()
```

Output 1:

```
defaultdict 0.0003848075866699219
if else 0.0002579689025878906
try/except 0.0004780292510986328
```

Output 2:

```
defaultdict 0.0005650520324707031
if else 0.00036215782165527344
try/except 0.00080108642578125
```

Output 3:

```
defaultdict 0.0006802082061767578
if else 0.0004029273986816406
try/except 0.0008919239044189453
```

In this case, `if/else` performed better.

Comment: Based on the outputs you posted, it looks like 'if else' is faster in all 3 cases while 'try/except' is slowest. Am I missing something?

Comment: omg, I didn't pay attention to the results. edited, thanks!